# How to convert from XWPFDocument to HWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to convert from  XWPFDocument to HWPFDocument :

I am trying to convert  XWPFDocument to HWPFDocument  but I am getting Exception as mentioned below.

Exception:- `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument`

```
public class test{
    File docFile=new File(fileName) 
    FileInputStream finStream = new FileInputStream(docFile.getAbsolutePath());
        String myDocFileName = String.valueOf(docFile);
        HWPFDocument doc = null;
        XWPFDocument docx = null;
        if (String.valueOf(myDocFileName.contains(".docx")) == "true") {
            docx = new XWPFDocument(finStream);
            Object o = docx;
           doc = (HWPFDocument) o;///Getting Exception here.......

        } 
        else {
            doc = new HWPFDocument(finStream);
            WordExtractor wordExtract = new WordExtractor(doc);
            myHTML = wordExtract.getText();
         }
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to cast one to the other? (Which won't ever work, as you've found)

Comment: I need only HWPFDocument object.So I converting XWPFDocument to HWPFDocument

Comment: "I've got an apple and I want an orange. How do I make my apple orange?" - that's basically what you're asking. Just because both are "fruit" (work with word documents) doesn't mean one is the same as the other